# Remove Common Elements from 2 Lists of List<DateTime> Flutter Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have these 2 list of Date Time:

```
 List l1 = ["2021-08-02 14:10:00.000, 2021-08-02 14:15:00.000"];
 List l2 = ["2021-08-02 13:40:00.000, 2021-08-02 13:45:00.000, 2021-08-02 13:50:00.000, 2021-08-02 13:55:00.000, 2021-08-02 14:00:00.000, 2021-08-02 14:05:00.000, 2021-08-02 14:10:00.000, 2021-08-02 14:15:00.000"];
```

I need to **extract and remove the common elements** between **l1** and **l2**. I tried it using this method:

```
l2.removeWhere((element) => l1.contains(element));
print(l2);
```

But, it just gives null. Am I doing something wrong here?

I removed the ("") and tried it in Dart Pad. There it seems to work just fine.

### Dart Pad Code

```
void main() {
List l1 = [2021-08-02 14:10:00.000, 2021-08-02 14:15:00.000];
List l2 = [2021-08-02 13:40:00.000, 2021-08-02 13:45:00.000, 2021-08-02 13:50:00.000, 
2021-08-02 13:55:00.000, 2021-08-02 14:00:00.000, 2021-08-02 14:05:00.000, 2021-08-02 
14:10:00.000, 2021-08-02 14:15:00.000];
l1.removeWhere((element)=> l2.contains(element));
print(l1);
}
```

### Output

```
[2021-08-02 14:10:00.000, 2021-08-02 14:15:00.000]
```

Can Anybody help me out here.

Comment: When you have "" it is actually a complete one element that too of type string! the dartpad one is correct

Comment: In your first code, you are not properly adding `"`, All those values are inside a single `""`. Means those lists contains 1 string each. You won't get null, I don't know how you got that. In your second dart-pad code, it's syntactically wrong. I'm not sure how it gave you correct result as you claim!!!

Comment: Do you have `List`s of actual `DateTime` objects, `List`s of `String`s, or `List`s where each contains a single, giant `String`?  It's very unclear from your question, especially since your DartPad code is not valid code.

Comment: @jamesdlin I have a list of DateTime objets.

Comment: @KrishBhanushali The Dart Pad code gives error in VS code

Comment: Please post actual code that demonstrates the problem you're encountering.

Comment: @jamesdlin separating them with "" for each element as given in the first answer worked. Thank you for helping anyways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list declaration is wrong, you need to declare your values in the list with ''. Try below in dartpad

```
  void main() {
List l1 = ['2021-08-02 14:10:00.000', '2021-08-02 14:15:00.000'];
List l2 = ['2021-08-02 13:40:00.000', '2021-08-02 13:45:00.000', 
'2021-08-02 14:15:00.000'];
l1.removeWhere((element)=> l2.contains(element));
print(l1);
}
```

Comment: Worked. Thank You for your time and effort.

Answer (score -1):

The way you are declaring your list, your list l1 and l2 each contains only one item. You need to update the list declaration -

```
  List l1 = ["2021-08-02 14:10:00.000", "2021-08-02 14:15:00.000"];
  List l2 = ["2021-08-02 13:40:00.000", "2021-08-02 13:45:00.000", "2021-08-02 13:50:00.000", "2021-08-02 13:55:00.000", "2021-08-02 14:00:00.000", "2021-08-02 14:05:00.000", "2021-08-02 14:10:00.000", "2021-08-02 14:15:00.000"];

  final commonElements =
  l1.toSet().intersection(l2.toSet()).toList();
  print(commonElements);
  
  //if you want to remove common form l1
  l1.removeWhere((element)=> commonElements.contains(element));
  print(l1);

  //if you want to remove common form l2
  l2.removeWhere((element)=> commonElements.contains(element));
  print(l2);
```